# Browse With not using Launch URL?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.net 5 project (VS 2015 Community), which is configured with the following debug options:

- To serve on port 53487,
- To launch url localhost:3000

This is because I am using "browsersync" as a proxy to the asp.net server on port 53487, and which serves up on port 3000.

When I "play" the project, the asp.net server starts up on port 53487 and then the browser opens  as expected on url: localhost:3000

This is all as desired.

However, if I use the "Browse With" option in order to select multiple browsers:

[image: multiplebroswers]

When those browsers open up, they are all pointing to localhost:53487 - they don't honour the launch url that I have configured..

This seems like a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Here are my project settings:

[image: Project Settings]